# PHP - CDF Binomial Distribution

Tags: php, laravel, statistics, distribution

I'm looking for an ideal way to calculate and handle CDF binomial distribution in PHP.

Currently I have modularised functions for LogGamma, Incomplete Regularized Beta and the actual Binomial Distribution function itself, but I'm searching for a better way to handle this.

**What I've looked into**

I've noticed the PECL library has the *stats_cdf_binomial* function, but there isn't much documentation anywhere on how to use it which makes things a little tricky:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.stats-cdf-binomial.php

I'm not sure if there's any other PHP statistics libraries out there that would be able to cater for this, but so far I haven't found anything useful.

**My issue**

I'm debugging the current functions I have and would rather illeviate this to a trusted library to handle such calculations to confirm their accuracy.

**My questions**

1) Is there another way to handle doing CDF binomial distribution within PHP?

2) Are there any fallbacks/cons doing it in a language like this?

3) If so, what other options are there?

Kindest regards :)